# Can any irrational number be expressed by z√y = y^(1/z)

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, irrational-numbers

In particular, for example, what integers $z,y$ are such that $\sqrt 2 + 3 \sqrt{25} = z\sqrt{y}$?
( I mean $25^{1/3}$)

Can this always be done for any expression on the lefthand side, for integers and the operations $+,-,*,/,$ and $√$ ?

Is there a procedure for turning any expression into $y^{1/z}$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: No, no, a sum of radicals can be another radical only in very fortunate cases (like all are rational multiples of a given radical).

Comment: By "$z \sqrt y$" do you mean "$\root z \of y$"?

Comment: @Orest Bucicovschi hmmm I think at least for example $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} = \sqrt{5 + \sqrt{24}}$ and the sum can always be collapsed into a single radical of int + radical. Is that what you mean? Because 2 and 3 are rational multiples of each other

Comment: Still $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ is not some radical of a rational number, this is what I meant. But you can have $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{8}= \sqrt{18}$, since they are all rational multiples of $\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all irrational numbers can be expressed as $y^{\frac{1}{z}}$ for $y, z $ integers. If an irrational number can be expressed in this way, it would mean that it is an algebraic number. Not all irrationals are algebraic. For example $\pi.$

Comment: Cool. If $a$ is an algebraic number, then does there exist two integers $z,y$ | $a = y^{(1/z)}$ ?

Comment: Take $1 + \sqrt{2}$ for example. This is an algebraic number but it is clear that any power of this will have a radical in its expression. Hence, no power of it will yield an integer.